# web scraping using excel and VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web, web-scraping, screen-scraping

i wrote my VBA code in excel sheet as below but it is not scrape data for me and also i don't know why please any one help me. it gave me reullt as "click her to read more" onlyi want to scrape enitre data such as first name last name state zip code and so on

```
Sub extractTablesData()
    Dim IE As Object, obj As Object
    Dim myState As String
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, t As Integer
    Dim elemCollection As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    myState = InputBox("Enter the city where you wish to work")

    With IE

        .Visible = True
        .navigate ("http://www.funeralhomes.com/go/listing/Search?  name=&city=&state=&country=USA&zip=&radius=")

        While IE.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

        For Each obj In IE.document.all.item("state").Options
            If obj.innerText = myState Then
                obj.Selected = True
            End If
        Next obj

        IE.document.getElementsByValue("Search").item.Click

        Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:K1500").ClearContents

        Set elemCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")

        For t = 0 To (elemCollection.Length - 1)

            For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
                For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
                Next c
            Next r
        Next t

    End With
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This is just such a bad idea... Scraping in general is a questionable approach, but doing it in VBA (eek) from inside an Excel workbook? You will never make this robust, no matter how hard you try. It's also going to be near-unmaintainable. If you need to scrape data into a workbook, either scrape it and use that to generate the workbook in the first place, or use a macro to talk to a database/process/api that handles the scraping for you.

Comment: I agree. It would be better to use something else for the web scraping and make that deliver an output that you can process into an Excel workbook.

Comment: @Basic - Outside the scope of this question (or perhaps not), but do you have any links/tips on how to get data from websites without scraping? I'm starting to get into data and analysis and such, and am curious why you are hesitant to scrape. Is it because it's generally a "manual" way to get data, when there are better ways of accessing it (via server, or something)?

Comment: @BruceWayne Sometimes scraping is the only option but... Almost everyone who wants you to have access to their data provides an API designed for the purpose. Those that don't are often trying to protect the data from use by others = there's usually a copyright issue. In addition, scraping is fragile as any change to page layout can break your code. The more flexible your scraping process, the more time/effort it requires to implement/maintain. You can get lost forever down that rabbit hole. In short, if I need data and there's no api, it's usually easiest to get them to add one. ...

Comment: (cont) That could be anything from asking nicely, paying a licensing fee, or even sponsoring the development work. It's almost always cleaner, easier and (counting developer salaries) cheaper in the long-run. If you are going to scrape, make certain you understand any legal terms / conditions associated with using the data.

Comment: @Basic - thanks for your reply! I'll have to look in to APIs for sure. Cheers!

Comment: I don't get the negative views here on this topic. There are times when scraping is perfectly appropriate to achieve data related tasks and Excel can be a great tool to do it. Not every online service is going to want to build an API to allow users to access their data.

Comment: Having said that, @vishnu has actually written his target site and they do state: `No commercial use or disemination of information on our website is permisable, any company found using or exploiting the information on our website will be violating copyright laws and will be subject to all legal and civil remedies available by law.` So that is crossing some lines there...

Answer (score 1):

Using the same URL as the answer already given you could alternatively select with CSS selectors to get the elements of interest, and use split to get just the names and address parts from the text. We can also do away with the browser altogether to get faster results from first results page.

---

**Business name:**

You can get the name with the following selector (using paid listing example):

```
div.paid-listing .listing-title
```

This selects (sample view)

[image: CSS query] <sub>[Try](http://try.jsoup.org/~KDMJWuwP6poqMJGbZVxMmy84mRc)</sub>

---

**Address info:**

The associated descriptive information can be retrieved with the selector:

```
div.paid-listing .address-summary
```

And then using split we can parse this into just the address information.

---

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTitleAndAddress()
    Dim oHtml As HTMLDocument, nodeList1 As Object, nodeList2 As Object, i As Long
    Const URL As String = "http://www.funeralhomes.com/go/listing/ShowListing/USA/New%20York/New%20York"
    Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set nodeList1 = oHtml.querySelectorAll("div.paid-listing .listing-title")
    Set nodeList2 = oHtml.querySelectorAll("div.paid-listing .address-summary")

    With Worksheets("Sheet3")
        .UsedRange.ClearContents
        For i = 0 To nodeList1.Length - 1
            .Range("A" & i + 1) = nodeList1.Item(i).innerText
            .Range("B" & i + 1) = Split(nodeList2.Item(i).innerText, Chr$(10))(0)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Example output:**

[image: Output]

Comment: Let me know if you try this please?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, without an API, this can be very tricky at best, and very inconsistent at worst.  For now, you can try the script below.

```
Sub DumpData()

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

URL = "http://www.funeralhomes.com/go/listing/ShowListing/USA/New%20York/New%20York"

'Wait for site to fully load
IE.Navigate2 URL
Do While IE.Busy = True
   DoEvents
Loop

RowCount = 1

With Sheets("Sheet1")
   .Cells.ClearContents
   RowCount = 1
   For Each itm In IE.document.all
      If itm.classname Like "*free-listing*" Or itm.classname Like "*paid-listing*" Then
        .Range("A" & RowCount) = itm.classname
        .Range("B" & RowCount) = Left(itm.innertext, 1024)
            RowCount = RowCount + 1
      End If

   Next itm
End With
End Sub
```

You probably want some kind of input box to capture the city and state and radius from the user, or capture those variable in cells in your worksheet.

```
Notice, the '%20' is a space character.
```

I got this idea from a friend of mine, Joel, a long time ago.  That guy is great!